# Looping and slicing through string

Tags: python, loops, slice

```
w = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']   
l = []

a = w[0:2]
b = w[2:4]
c = w[4:6]
d = w[6:8]


l = [a,b,c,d]              #[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']]
```

How can i get the same result ('w' to 'l') using loop method instead of slicing multiple times? Assuming  i dont know how many characters can there be in 'w' variable (in this example it is just from 'a' to 'h'), and slicing will always start from 0 but the range in unknown(where in this example it is 0:2)

Thank You very much.

Comment: is it important to have them assigned to `a`,`b`,`c`, and `d` or you just need `l` to equal what you have there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `range` function with list comprehension

```
w = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']   
length = 2
step = 2
l = [w[i:i + length] for i in range(0,len(w),step)]
l
#[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']]
```